# Rest Assured | Why getting repeated errors when trying to automate apis using rest assured?

Tags: test-automation-framework, api-testing, rest-api, rest-assured

I have just set up rest assured framework and implemented it as a maven project. My pom.xml has the below mentioned dependencies

```
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  
  
  <!-- To parse json Document -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- To validate that a json response conforms to a json schema -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- To parse xml document -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Testing framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest Used for Regex -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  
</dependencies>  
</project>
```

And my code looks like

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LrnAsServiceApis {
    

    @Test
    public void trackvialrnumber() {
        
        given().get("lt-api.delta.com/v1/fulltrack/ABCD").then().log().all();
    }
```

But when I run it as TestNg I get error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject`

And when I try to fix this by adding groovy all dependency I get another error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase
```

And when I add another dependency, I get another error and this becomes never ending and frustrating. Is it that cumbersome? How do I fix once and for all?

Comment: Show us how you describe dependency in your pom.xml and how exactly you're trying to run your code.

Comment: Alexey, I have described the dependencies in the question. I run it as a TestNG Test.

Comment: Try to leave only "io.rest-assured rest-assured 3.0.2 test" and "org.testng testng 6.10 test"

Comment: Doesn't work! Same errors.

Comment: Is your code under main folder or under test folder?

Comment: It is in a class under test folder.

Comment: And you run your tests from IDE? or from command-line?

Comment: I run it from Eclipse IDE. Run it as a TestNG test.

Comment: You are missing some jar that contains the file HttpRequestBase.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with scope of the Rest Assured dependency in the `pom.xml` file

If your running your Rest Assured test from `src/main/java` the scope should be `compile` and your dependency will be as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and if your running your Rest Assured test from `src/test/java` the scope should be `test` and your dependency will be as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Solution** is to change the scope to `compile` for rest assured dependency in `pom.xml` file

**Reference:** https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

> compile:This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

> test:This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases. This scope is not transitive.